# How to know the name of a model attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given the following example code:

```
@user = User.last
user.first_name.attr_name #this should return "first_name"
```

Is there something like the "attr_name" method in Rails?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this (but maybe ask yourself why):

```
user.attributes.key(user.first_name)
```

...will return `"first_name"` as a String.

Comment: shorter version: `attributes.key(value)`

Comment: WOW. I never knew about that. Thanks!

Comment: Actually `user.attributes.key(user.first_name)` did work for me, but  `attributes.key(value)` not. Thanks anyway for both

Comment: `value` in that case refers to any arbitrary value you would enter. For example, if your user was named "John", and you ran `user.attributes.key("John")`, it would return `"first_name"`.

Answer (score 0):

To list the attributes of a model you can use `column_names`.

For example, `User.column_names` returns something like:

> ["id", "email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip", "created_at", "updated_at", "name", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "confirmation_sent_at", "account_id", "account_primary"]

You can then iterate through this array. For example, `User.column_name[1]` would return `"email"`.

To view more details of each attribute, just use `columns`.  The output of `User.columns` would look like this:

> [#< ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter::Column:0x007fd6942b1840 @name="id", @sql_type="int(11)", @null=false, @limit=4, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @type=:integer, @default=nil, @primary=true, @coder=nil, @collation=nil>, #< ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter::Column:0x007fd694434348 @name="email", @sql_type="varchar(255)",...

To list attributes from an instance of a model you can take MrTheWalrus's suggestion: `User.first.attributes` would return a hash of the first user's attributes along with their values.

Hope this is helpful.